# GraphQL with Spring boot Java Validation type error for FieldUndefined

Tags: java, spring, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and am working on creating an entity and fetching an instance of that entity by an attribute. The entity is named UserProfile for which I have defined the schema as follows:

```
type UserProfile{
    id:String!
    username:String!
    // A huge list of other attributes
}

type Query {
    getUserProfile(username:String!):UserProfile!
}

type Mutation {
    addUserProfile(username:String!):Boolean!
}
```

I also defined the Controllers for it which implement a GraphQLQueryResolver and a GraphQLMutationResolver respectively for the Query and Mutation types. The code for them is:

```
@Component
public class UserProfileGraphQLMutationController implements GraphQLMutationResolver {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Boolean addUserProfile(String username) {
        logger.info("Searching for user: "+username);
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
        // Setting fields to null or blanks here
        userProfile.setUsername(username);

        UserProfile savedUserProfile = userProfileRepository.insert(userProfile);
        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/users/{username}").buildAndExpand(savedUserProfile.getUsername()).toUri();
        ResponseEntity obj = ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
        return obj.getStatusCode().equals("200");
    }
}



@Component
public class UserProfileGraphQLController implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    @Transactional
    public UserProfile getUserProfile(String username) {
        logger.info("Fetching Profile for User: "+username);
        return userProfileRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to query it using postman, I get the fieldUndefined error. I am able to use similar queries and mutations for other entities that I have in the application. The mutations and queries I am using to create them are:

```
mutation {
    addUserProfile(username:"MummyGupta")
}

query {
    getUserProfile(username:"MummyGupta"){
        username
        posts
    }
}
```

The error In receive is:

- "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'getUserProfile' in type 'Query' is undefined @ 'getUserProfile'",
- "description": "Field 'getUserProfile' in type 'Query' is undefined",
- "validationErrorType": "FieldUndefined",
- "queryPath": [
  "getUserProfile"
  ],
- "errorType": "ValidationError",
- "path": null,
- "extensions": null

I would like to know what I am doing wrong or what I have missed. Thanks for reading this and trying to solve it in advance!